# Unable to load data with quotes in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I need to load a string that contains quotes as given below..The data is being loaded using mysqldb python package...

```
Value = " all leading to the epic "Zero Year." "
```

Error

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'Zero Year.""
```

How can I load strings that contain quotes within it...

Comment: No, that is *not* how you are defining `Value`, because that isn't even valid Python syntax. Please show the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an escape character, i.e. " all leading to the epic \"Zero Year.\" "